# Save archive to Documents folder

Tags: ios, xcode, download

Here is the code I have for downloading an archive and saving it to my Documents folder:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resource] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

NSData *receivedData;
NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSError *requestError;

int i = 3;

while (i)    //Try 3 times
{
    receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:&requestError];

    if (receivedData)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else i--;
}

if (!receivedData)
{
    NSLog(@"************************************************");
    NSLog(@"**  Error downloading data for resource : %@  **", resource);
    NSLog(@"************************************************");
}
else
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath;
    dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:LIST_FOLDER];
    NSError *documentError;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])    //Create folder
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&documentError];
    }

    NSLog(@"saveError = %@", documentError);   //Prints out null so no problem here

    NSError *writeError;

    [receivedData writeToFile:dataPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];

    NSLog(@"write error = %@", writeError);
```

The last nslog prints out the following and won't save the archive:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" "The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory"}
```

The subfolder in the Documents directory gets created but it is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write the data to the folder. You need to write it to a file in the folder.

`dataPath` is the directory you create. You need to append a filename to that path and then write the file to that full path (with filename).

Comment: I want to save the files with their names (may not always be the same) can't I get them from the archive?

Comment: Also, I know that NSUrlConnection can unarchive my files when downloading them. How can I do that?